# How to solve when ampps don't run on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: linux, apache, installation, runtime-error, ampps

how can I resolve the issue when AMPPS 3.8 don't display any option when opened on Ubuntu 18.4?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AMPPS is a stack of Apache, MySQL, MongoDB, PHP, Perl and Python. What exactly is not running on your Ubuntu machine? Did you check the error logs for more details?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i'm new to AMPPS, where can I find the error log?